# Is the unit circle $C$ Jordan-negligible in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, circles

Let us consider the unit circle $C \in \mathbb R^2 := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \lvert x^2+y^2=1\}$ and the Jordan content defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure). A set $X$ is Jordan-negligible if $\forall \epsilon > 0, X$ is covered by a finite family of hyper-rectangles (or bricks, i.e. product of closed intervals) and the sum of their volumes is bounded by $\epsilon$.

I know that the circle $C:= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^2 \lvert x^2+y^2=1, z=0\}$ is Jordan-negligible in $\mathbb R^3$ (covered by the hyper-rectangle $[-1,1] \times [-1,1] \times [-\frac{\epsilon}{8},\frac{\epsilon}{8}])$.

But is the unit circle $C$ Jordan-negligible in $\mathbb R^2$ ? (i.e. $\forall \epsilon$, can we cover this circle with rectangles and the sum of their areas must be smaller than $ \epsilon$ ?)

Edit : We know that a set $X$ is Jordan-measurable $\iff \partial X$ is negligible. Knowing that the circle $C$ (closed set) in $\mathbb R^2$ is equal to its boundary ($C = \partial C$), we can show that $$\int_C \mathbb 1_C(x) dx \text{ is Riemann-integrable on } C \iff C \text{ is measurable} \iff \partial C=C \text{ is negligible} $$

Answer (score 3):

tl; dr: *Yes*.

Here's a sketch: If $n$ is a positive integer, subdivide the portion of the circle in the first quadrant into $n$ arcs of length $\ell = \frac{\pi}{2n}$. Since each arc is a monotone graph, it is covered by the rectangle with opposite corners at the ends of the arc, whose area is at most $\ell^{2}$. We have therefore covered a quarter circle by $n$ rectangles of total area at most $n\ell^{2}$.

A similar argument handles the image of any sufficiently smooth (e.g., continuously-differentiable) path.